# ValidateUser in System.Web.Security takes simple password

Tags: c#

I am using the `ValidateUser` method provided by `System.Web.Security`.

However, I thought password is used in the following method should be encyrpted, but it is not, it is just taken the plain simple password, which I believe is not secure.

I wonder how I need to convert my `saltedpassword` into plain simple password in order to use in the following method

**Implementation**

```
var isAuthenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
```

Comment: How is this not secure? Can anyone malicious read the content of the password variable at runtime? Also, your method does not encrypt your password, it hashes it. An hash function is a one-way function; you cannot un-hash it.

Comment: I am sending this info from mobile device to wcf service, someone may easily tune into it and read all sensitive information.

Comment: That's why you encrypt your connection via SSL.

Comment: do not use SSL at the moment.

Comment: Then you have wayyyyyy bigger security issues.

Answer (score 3):

The membership provider manages the password hashing in the user store. The call to ValidateUser takes the raw password as ValidateUser will perform the same hash to check against the store. Thus you don't need to hash or salt the password yourself.

Comment: could you please elaborate with an example? The password is hashed on the mobile device,  how could I able to retrieve the original password to use ValidateUser method?

Comment: Client-side hashing is a terrible idea. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so-uncommon

Comment: @hotspring You should never be able to retrieve the *original* password.

Comment: TyCobb is correct, you cannot ever get the original password back. The Membership Provider should be performing a one-way hash. If someone does "forgot password" you can have the Membership Provider send them a temporary password or use a reset link.